# Gnuplot set encoding utf8 doesnt work

Tags: utf-8, gnuplot, encode

I have gnuplot(version 4.6 patchlevel 5) on Windows 8. I would like to set encofing utf8. I save my source in UTF8 encoding. My source test.txt:

```
set terminal pdf enhanced size 16cm,8cm font ", 10"
set output "Slozitost/Slozitost.pdf"
set encoding utf8
set grid
set datafile separator ","
set title "Složitost" font ",10"
set key left top title "Legenda" box
set xdata time 
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y"
set xrange ["03/01/2009":"20/04/2014"]
set format y "%10.0f"
#set yrange [-50:14000000]
set format x "%m/%y"
set xtics 6*30*24*60*60
#set ytics 100
set lmargin  13
set rmargin  2
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 noborder
plot 'Slozitost.csv' using 1:2 title "Slozitost" with lines linecolor rgb "blue" lw 3
```

I tried compile source by gnuplot terminal. Gnuplot terminal said to me this error:

```
gnuplot> load "test.txt"
          ^
         "test.txt", line 1: invalid character »
```

What is wrong??

Comment: This error seems to be happening on line 1 of your code, so before you actually set the encoding. I honestly do not have experience with encoding stuff on gnuplot but it looks like gnuplot does not like some character in your script. Just an idea: have you tried `set encoding utf8` *before* `load "test.txt"`?

Comment: yes...it does the same thing...I don't understand why terminal doesn't recognise test.txt (test.txt has utf8 encode)

Answer (score 5):

I think this happens if your file has a BOM marker at the beginning. Gnuplot cannot handle this. To remove that, see the documentation of your editor.

If this is the source of the error, the code should work fine if you copy and paste it into the interactive terminal.

BTW: There is no need to post such a big script which we cannot run (we don't have the data file). A minimal script which could show the problem would be something like

```
set encoding utf8
plot x title "Složitost"
```

which would also narrow down the source of your problem :)

Comment: When I write these letters "řřšřšřý" in gnuplot terminal(on Widnows). Terminal of gnuplot doesn't recognise them. It's also strange...

Comment: This is obviously not a solution to your problem, but maybe you could have a look at one of the latex terminals and input your special text via latex syntax.

Comment: Does the minimal script, which I provided work: 1. when you copy&paste it into the gnuplot terminal? 2. When you write it to a file and load it with `load 'myfile.txt'`?